# wx.SetTextForeground doesn't set DC color properly in wxPython

Tags: python, wxwidgets

I have the following code and I'm trying to change the text color of DC. I have searched the internet and found that SetTextForeground should be used for this, but somehow I'm unable to make it work.

```
import wx

class GUI():        
    def __init__(self):
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.window  = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Example Title")

        textList = ['text1', 'text2']
        for i in range(len(textList)):
            bmp = wx.Image('images/step_background.png').Rescale(160, 40).ConvertToBitmap()
            bmp = self.drawTextOverBitmap(bmp, textList[i])
            control = wx.StaticBitmap(self.window, -1, bmp, (0, 30*i+20), size=(160,30))
        self.window.Show()


    def drawTextOverBitmap(self, bitmap, text='', color=(0, 0, 0)):
            dc = wx.MemoryDC(bitmap)
            dc.SetTextForeground(color)
            w,h = dc.GetSize()
            tw, th = dc.GetTextExtent(text)
            dc.DrawText(text, (w - tw) / 2, (h - th) / 2) #display text in center
            return bitmap

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    gui = GUI()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Do you have any ideas what am I doing wrong? I would be grateful for any idea.

Thank you

Comment: Your code works for me. It displays text1 and text2 on the images.

Comment: Yes, the text is displayed fine, but I can't change its color. By default it should be black (because of color=(0, 0, 0)).

Comment: So what colour _is_ it for you? Black is the default foreground colour anyhow, so I have a lot of trouble seeing how could it possibly be anything else...

Comment: Basically it looks like the text is transparent so it 'inherits' the color of background (which in my case is dark grey). What I want is to change it to any color I want. By default I set it to be black, but in real usage it will have a different color. Anyway as I said, it has the grey color instead of black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, transparency is the issue here. Tried your code on a non-transparent image and it works fine displaying the color you set.

Quoting from the [official docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_d_c.html):

> In general wxDC methods don't support alpha transparency and the alpha
>   component of wxColour is simply ignored and you need to use
>   wxGraphicsContext for full transparency support.

So try creating a graphics context like:

```
        dc = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
        gc = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)
        font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
        gc.SetFont(font, "Red")
        w,h = dc.GetSize()
        tw, th = dc.GetTextExtent(textList[i])
        gc.DrawText(textList[i], (w - tw) / 2, (h - th) / 2)
```

Comment: This one actually worked! I'm quite a novice with wxWidgets (as well as GUI creation), so I don't have much overview about Contexts. Thank you for helping me out. :-)